# Firewall rule for ClockworkMod Tether

Tags: linux, firewall, tethering

After 2 hours for googling, I finally for ClockworkMod tether to compile and run on Fedora 17 x64. Only catch is I have to disable firewall when I am running it, and I am not comfortable doing that. I would like to add a rule to firewall to allow this particular application through it. Is there a way I can do that? If not has anyone figured out the ports that I need to opened?

Comment: use `tcpdump -i eth0` to identify the ports, where eth0 is the interface that is connected to the internet

Answer (score 1):

I have just been through this process myself. I am using openvpn VPN client on the phone and VPNBook VPN provider and clockworkmod tether:

The rules I added to make things work are:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp -s 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT     # Tethered phone?
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT    # NTP.
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 50001 -j ACCEPT  # Clockworkmod node process on Linux.
```

Can add the following to firestarter's /etc/firestarter/user-post file:

```
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -p udp -s 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 50001 -j ACCEPT
```

I need to do further investigation to see what 8.8.8.8 is and to lock down to specific NTP servers.

Hope this helps.